# Multi-Threaded write operation in Array

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex, atomic

I have a program in which multiples threads update the value of an array.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
HANDLE Mutex;
    int n = 100;
static DWORD WINAPI ThreadedUpdate(LPVOID param){
    DWORD GetMutex;
    GetMutex = WaitForSingleObject(Mutex,INFINITE);
    if(GetMutex == WAIT_ABANDONED){
        std::cout << "Error : Could not get Mutex for working Thread. " << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(GetMutex == WAIT_OBJECT_0){
        int* a = (int*) param;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            a[i] += 100;
    }
    if(!ReleaseMutex(Mutex)){
        std::cout << "Error : Could not relese Mutex." << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int numThreads = 50;
    int* a = new int[n];
    HANDLE* Th = new HANDLE[numThreads];
    Mutex = CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,NULL);
    DWORD t;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        a[i] = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < numThreads ; i++)
        Th[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadedUpdate,(void*)a,0,&t); 
    WaitForMultipleObjects(numThreads, Th, TRUE, INFINITE);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
    std::getchar();
}
```

Now, in the above program, i am using a mutex for synchronization. But what I have observe is that even if i do not use synchronization, the answer i am getting is correct. Does it mean locks are not needed in this case. Is += operator is atomic? 
This is just a sample program. I am using a similar code in a machine learning algorithm where multiple threads are updating a vector. Even in that case, i am getting expected output without using lock. Using a lock is making the program very slow as the updates are very frequent. 
 I just want to make sure that if i do not use lock will there be any problem?

Comment: It likely means the time it takes you to cycle in you loop to setup and launch the next thread is longer than the previous thread takes to complete. Its also completely unpredictable, so don't think you can get away with it all the time (or even now). Oh, and you're leaking thread handles, but I doubt you'll care since the process is about to terminate anyway.

Comment: So what are the options apart from using locks? is there any lock which is fast to acquire and release? also what do you mean by leaking thread handles?

Comment: Second part first, I mean you (correctly) save all those thread handles in an array to wait on them after the creation loop, but they should *each* still be closed using `CloseHandle()` once you no longer need them. For the first, you could try a critical section, which should have considerably better performance than the sledge-hammer of a mutex you're using. This is more a code-structure thing than anything else, honestly.

Comment: HI, I am new to multi-threaded programming. can you be more specific about critical sections? and thanks for the CloseHandle() part. certainly i was missing it.

Comment: Its Windows. [CRITICAL_SECTION objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx) are covered in the same area of the docs as mutex objects. They all fall under the guise of synchronization objects. Check the online help of DevStudio.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned it as well, the way this code is structured, your threads *must* run serially. I.e you're getting no benefit from threading *at all*. The entire functional embodiment of your thread procedure is under a mutex lock, which means you would be better off belaying that entirely and doing it all in a single thread in the first place. As written the performance can be nothing else but *worse* than a single thread solution. You *can* use atomic operations on the array slots and completely forego the mutex/critsec entirely. If you're interested in how, let me know.

Comment: Yes, i know there is no use of thread in this version of code. But this is just an example to make the problem more readable. in actual code, each thread get an index to a function and then releases the mutex. So, I am getting advantage of all the threads in actual code.

Comment: Can you partition your data to a fixed number of slices and have each thread take a single slice (the size of the slice is the dividend of the number of threads you're working with. In that, so long as no two threads are hitting the same data in each *others* slices, you don't need locks at all. It is common in multi-threaded divide and conquer algorithms over a fixed data set to do this, so give it some consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a mutex or critical section in this code, so long the all writes *and* reads in the multi-threaded environment are under atomic operations.

Atomics in Windows require `long` parameters, so start by changing your array to be `long` rather than `int`. Then, change the thread procedure to this:

```
static DWORD WINAPI ThreadedUpdate(LPVOID param)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        InterlockedAdd((long*)param + i, 100);
    return 0;
}
```

Test this with some huge arrays, and I think it will do what you want. Your `main()` is reduced to:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int numThreads = 50;
    long* a = new long[n];
    HANDLE* Th = new HANDLE[numThreads];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        a[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < numThreads ; i++)
        Th[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadedUpdate, a, 0, NULL); 

    WaitForMultipleObjects(numThreads, Th, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
    delete [] a;

    for (int i=0; i<numThreads; CloseHandle(Th[i++]));
    delete [] Th;

    std::getchar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But my actual arrays are floats. is there any atomic addition present for float.

Comment: @user2812133 Sorry, not really. I'd have to gel on that some more. I don't think you're going to pull that off without at least a CRITICAL_SECTION with the code as structured, but there still might be a way. I'll give a little more thought.